# How to return Continue Http status code in .NET Core WEB API?

Tags: api, http, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-1.0, http-status-code-100

I'm having troubles setting `100` status code on response.
I have tried the following way:

```
HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 100;
```

but it does not work, server refused to answer. Does anybody faced similar issue?

Comment: Can you provide more context about what you are trying to do in a [mcve] as well as clarify the platform you are working with. You could try `    return StatusCode(100);` in the action to return a response with a custom statuc code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of the Web API related action results in `Controller` to get the desired response.

```cs
//returns a response with specified status code
public IActionResult StatusCodeActionResult() {
    return StatusCode(100); //<-- StatusCodeResult
}

//returns a response with specified status code along with an object
public IActionResult StatusCodeWithObjectResult() {
    return StatusCode(100, new { Data = "HelloWorld" }); //<-- ObjectResult
}
```